# Python, fping, cron

Tags: python, cron, ping

I recently wrote a program in Python (first stab at said language) to grab ip addresses from a database, ping them using fping and throw the response times back into said database. App works great from command line, but breaks from crontab

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

PYTHON CODE -- I got most of this from the interwebs

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import MySQLdb as mdb;
import threading
import shlex  
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import subprocess

con = mdb.connect('localhost', '*****', '*****', '*****')

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip_list):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip_list = ip_list
    def run(self):
    get_ping(self.ip_list)

def get_simple_cmd_output(cmd):
    args = shlex.split(cmd)
    return Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False).communicate()[0]

def get_ping(ip_list):
    ip_response_dict = {}
    cmd = "fping -C 4 -q {host}".format(host=" ".join(ip_list))
    for x in get_simple_cmd_output(cmd).strip().split(' : ', 0) :
        lines = x.split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            if line.upper().find(":", 0) > 0:
                ip_data = line.split(":")
                ip_address = ip_data[0].strip()
                ip_response = ip_data[1].strip().split(" ")
                total = 0;
                length = 0;
                for ping_time in ip_response:
                    if ping_time != '' and ping_time != '-':
                        total += float(ping_time)
                        length += 1
                if total > 0 and length > 0:
                    ip_response_dict[ip_address] = (total / length)
                else:
                    ip_response_dict[ip_address] = 0
    save_ping_times(ip_response_dict)

def save_ping_times(ip_list):
    cursor = con.cursor()
    for key, value in ip_list.items():
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO `Tech_AP_Ping_Time`(`IP_Address`,`Value`) VALUES ("' + key + '","' + str(round(value, 2)) + '")')
    con.commit()

threads = []
chunk_length = 100

with con:
    cur = con.cursor(mdb.cursors.DictCursor)
   cur.execute("SELECT `IP_Address` FROM `Tech_APs` WHERE (`IP_Address` IS NOT NULL AND `IP_Address` != '') ORDER BY `IP_Address`")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    i = 0
    ip_list = []
    for row in rows:
        ip_list.append(row['IP_Address'])

ip_list = [ip_list[i : i + chunk_length] for i in range(0, len(ip_list), chunk_length)]

for ip_chunk in ip_list:
    thread = myThread(ip_chunk)
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
```

CRON COMMAND - Yes, I have a full path to the script set in my actual cron

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python distro_pinger.py
```

ERROR -- I am getting this when run from the cron

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/var/www/html/poller/distro_pinger.py", line 15, in run
    get_ping(self.ip_list)
  File "/var/www/html/poller/distro_pinger.py", line 25, in get_ping
    for x in get_simple_cmd_output(cmd).strip().split(' : ', 0) :
  File "/var/www/html/poller/distro_pinger.py", line 19, in get_simple_cmd_output
    return Popen(['fping','-C','4','-q','','127.0.0.1'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False).communicate()[0]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 639, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. (Even if it's you telling me that I did everything wrong :P)

Comment: What happens if you write the full path to `fping` in your script?

Comment: it's missing an 'a' in the title

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen, setting that full path worked. Would you put that as an answer please?

Comment: Naturally, glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the full path to `fping` in your script. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Which user is fping installed for? Is the crontab setting for this same user? If not, does the user under which the crontab setting is have permissions to the fping directory?